# No module named paramiko error while executing python script from ipython notebook

Tags: python, windows, ipython, jupyter-notebook, paramiko

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-2ae261e7bd39> in <module>()
          1 import sys
          2 #sys.stderr = open('/dev/null')       # Silence silly warnings from paramiko
    ----> 3 import paramiko as pm
          4 from paramiko import AutoAddPolicy
          5 sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__

ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

I'm new to python/paramiko, and just started using ipython notebook to run python/paramiko scripts, but while executing the script, I get the error given above.

I'd installed python27 and pycrypto and paramiko modules earlier and still I can run the .py script from my windows cmd prompt. But, then I installed anaconda and now if I try to run the same from IPython Notebook it fails but it runs from the cmd prompt since the python paramiko is in path.

How can I install paramiko specifically in ipython's site-packages directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda uses its own packages, it won't use those installed with your previous Python installation. If you are using IPython with anaconda, you need to install paramiko with conda:

```
conda install paramiko
```

Comment: thanks man, I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried, after a system restart it worked.